# Asp.net Core An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Session

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

### Problem

I am setting session in login controller after successfully login when I redirect it to application Home Index page to show username at nav bar I am getting session butt it gives me this error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Session

### Code in index.cshtml

```
@if (@HttpContext.Session.GetString("Name") != null)
{
    <a href="/Account/Sigout" class="btn btn-outline-primary d-block">@HttpContext.Session.GetString("Name")</a>                
}
```

Comment: take a look at this. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877349/accessing-session-object-inside-an-asp-core-2-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877349/accessing-session-object-inside-an-asp-core-2-view)

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/51939627/2238515 solved for me