# Accessing Session object inside an Asp Core 2 View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to show Session in view. Is that possible? 
I try with this in my view

```
<div class="content-header col-xs-12">
   <h1>Welcome, @HttpContext.Session.GetString("userLoggedName")</h1>
</div>
```

But i get an error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error 
>   **CS0120**    **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Session'**

Any help,  i will appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` implementation to your view and use it to get the Session object

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
<h1>@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("userLoggedName")</h1>
```

Assuming you already have everything setup for enabling session in the Startup class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession(s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    services.AddMvc();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();  // This line is needed

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    });
}
```

Comment: Yes. We can do that now with asp net core.  No need to pass stuff via ViewBag or so. ;)

Comment: But i get this `The type or namespace name 'IHttpContextAccessor' could not be found`, and i already setup for enabling session in the Startup class.

Comment: You should add `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` to the top of your view. I updated the answer with that.

Comment: but, Why?? why Microsoft is doing that to all its fans?

Comment: For anyone else, you also need `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` in `ConfigureServices()` if you get that error from @AndhikaKurniaAufaAzham