# Cannot access Session object inside a helper class within my Asp.Net Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to access the HttpContext.Session object in a helper class within my ASP.NET Core 2.1 project.

When I try to access HttpContext.Session I get the following error.

> CS0120    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Session'

With .NET 4.x ASP.NET, it was easily accessed with "HttpContext.Current.Session".

Here is my class:

```
 public class MySession
 {

    public void Foo()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Name", "The Doctor"); // will not work
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Age", 773);  // will not work

    }
 }
```

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            services.Configure<ServiceSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ServiceSettings"));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Do I need to inject something into the MySession class?

Comment: add httpcontext accessor so that you can get access to the session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the Session in ASP.NET Core via static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785767/how-to-access-the-session-in-asp-net-core-via-static-variable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still access `Session` via the `HttpContext`. You how ever have to access the session via the `IHttpContextAccessor`, which as the name implies, will allow access to the `HttpContext` external to controllers and other framework classes that have it as a local member.

First you need to add the accessor to the DI container.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

[API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpservicecollectionextensions.addhttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

from there you need to inject it into the desired class and access the desired members

```
public class MySession {
    IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public MySession(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public void Foo() {
        var httpContext = accessor.HttpContext;
        httpContext.Session.SetString("Name", "The Doctor");
        httpContext.Session.SetInt32("Age", 773);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this in controller or razor page @Nkosi

Answer (score 1):

We also need to initialise the session object

```
    private ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
```

Complete solution is below. Just in case anyone couldn't work out (like me) with above code.

```
Public class SomeOtherClass {

private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
private ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

public SomeOtherClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

public void TestSet()
{
    _session.SetString("Test", "Ben Rules!");
}

public void TestGet()
{
    var message = _session.GetString("Test");
} }
```

Code taken from [Using Sessions and HttpContext in ASP.NET Core and MVC Core](https://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/)

Comment: problem here could not use my ISession extensions